# C++ n-arry tree with different elements

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to build a n-arry tree from a document. For that i have 3 different types of elements for the tree:

- Struct Nodes

  - Have a name
  - can contain other Nodes
  - Depth
- Element Node (Leaf of the tree)

  - Have a Key
  - Have a value
  - Depth
- Element Template Node (Leaf of the tree)

  - Have a placeholder which should be resolved later in the program
  - Depth

At the moment i think about something like this:

```cpp
class Node {
    public:
        Node(int depth);
        int depth() const;
    private:
        int depth_;
};

class StructNode : public Node {
    ...
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
};

class ElementNode : public Node {
...
};

class ElementTemplateNode : public Node {
...
};
```

The Tree will be generated from an File on Startup and reused to create an output string like this:

```
Structname:
   key = value
   key = value
   Structname:
       key = value
   Structname:
       key = value
...
```

Where the Key and value where directly read from the `ElementNode` or read from another file with the value of the `placeholder` inside the `ElementTemplateNode`

Is there maybe a better Structure for the Tree? Because with the current one i have to check first if its a `StructNode`, `ElementNode` or `ElementTemplateNode`

Comment: Interesting that you have to check the type.  Sounds like a polymorphism problem.  Maybe talk more about that aspect of it.  What operation are you doing where you need to check the specific type of the Node?

Comment: First of all as soon as you have inheritance and keep objects by pointer to a base class you have to add virtual destructor to the base, `Node` in your case.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;` careful with this. While this construct is correct, if your structure grows in depth, you might end up with destructors overflowing the stack due to a long chain of unique ptrs destroying their children. And your base structure is missing the virtual destructor.

Comment: BTW, I'm not entirely sure, but wouldn't sth like [boost::property_tree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html) suffice for your needs?

Comment: @alagner what would be a better way to store the child's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical structure for implementing a tree with different kind of nodes.  Another variant would be the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

The problem that you describe, is usually caused by asking the nodes about what they know, instead of telling them what to do.  If you'd do it the other way round ([tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)), you could get rid of those checks and benefit from polymorphism.

The different kind of nodes inherit from `Node`. You could design your tree using a uniform interface, with virtual functions defined for `Node` which then can be overridden for the different types of nodes. Calling the method would then do the right things, without need for a manual type check.  For generating the output string, you'd tell the root node to generate a string. If it's a structure, it would add the heading and tell its children to generate a string, but if it's a leaf it would just add the key/value pair to the string.  No need from outside to know anything about each node.

If the operation of exploring the tree shall not be implemented by the tree itself, the usual approach is to use a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  The big advantage is that you write the vistor once, and it's then easy to specialize a new kind of visitor for different algorithms.  Again, no need to check the type of the nodes.  The pattern makes sure that the right elementary function is called for the right type of node.

Comment: I also thought about adding the printing to the node but then I need to pass the other document or a pointer to it to the print statement so that I'm able to resolve the placeholders in the `ElementTemplateNode`. That's why I'm not sure if the structure at the moment is the best fit